# Time Complexity of a simple piece of Code

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Here is a simple piece of code. What's it's time complexity?

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    String temp="";
    for(int j=i;j<n;j++){
        temp+=S.charAt(j);
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

**N<=5000**

The code above is giving me `TLE` while the next simple code gives me `Wrong Answer`:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    String temp ="";
    for(int j=i;j<n;j++){

    }
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Comment: Voting to reopen, question is perfectly clear, and is "What is the time complexity of my code"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Complexity is actually `O(n^3)`**, if ignoring JIT optimizations (and most possibly online judges turns that off). Since `5000^3 ~= 1.2*10^11`, getting TLE is expected.

---

Explanation for time complexity:

Look at your code, and pay special attention to the comment I added:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
    String temp="";
    for(int j=i;j<n;j++){
        temp+=S.charAt(j);
        // ^^ THIS IS NOT O(1)^^
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

Each iteration of the inner loops takes `O(|temp|)` time, where `|temp|` is the length of `temp`.

Recall that `String` in java is immutable, and string concatination is actually creating a new object while copying the old underlying `char[]`, resulting in linear time operation.

So, let's examine the length of `temp`.

The length of `temp` is increasing by 1 for each iteration of the inner loop, and gets reset for each iteration of the outer loop.

So, the time taking for each iteration of the outer loop to execute is summation of all iterations of inner loops for certain `i`, which is:

```
Outer(n,i) = 1 + 2 + ... + n-i+1 = (n-i)(n-i+1)/2
```

Now, summing it up for all values of `i` gets us:

```
T(n) = sum {Outer(n,i) for i = 0,...,n} 
T(n) = (n-0)(n-0+1)/2 + (n-1)(n-1+1)/2 + ... + (n-n)(n-n+1)/2
T(n) = n(n+1)(n+2)/6
```

The [last equation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%28n-k%29%28n-k%2B1%29%2F2+k+from+0+to+n-1) is a variant of sum of squares.

We can see that `T(n)` is indeed in `O(n^3)`.

---

It can be significantly improved from O(n^3) to O(n^2) by using a [`StringBuider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Comment: Dear downvoter, please elaborate. My analysis is explained in details, where do you disagree with me?

Comment: That's a long ass way to say that string concatenation is linear when String is immutable (as it is in Java).

Comment: @amit, please consider the fact that temp is being reseted on each outer loop so final length of temp wouldn't be `n(n+1)/2`. Complexity of this algorithm is `O(n^3)`, correct me if I wrong.

Comment: @zv3dh  No, you are not, I missed that fact. Important addition of the answer to other (erroneous) answers is not ignoring the string concatination. I am editting per to your comment. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: @amit, thank you for focusing on string concatenation complexity.

Comment: @zv3dh updated it. Thanks again for pointing it out, would be glad if you have a look and see if I missed anything else.

Comment: @amit, looks great for me, thank you for maintaining the answer